# SAPUI5: Function call from other controller - how to instantiate controller or this.getView()?

Tags: javascript, function, controller, sapui5, instantiation

In my `MainController` ​I'd like to call a function from my `ManualUploadController` by pushing a button

The function call itself is working fine like this:

```
var oManualUploadController = new ManualUpload(); 
var backendData = oManualUploadController.onGenerateBackendData();
```

​However, in the `onGenerateBackendData()` method, I retrieve models for example like this:

```
var oModel = this.getView().getModel('odataDetails');
```

What's funny is:

The `ManualUploadController` creates a `Dialog` with some logic in it and the `MainController` is the "mainpage" from where the dialog gets opened.

When initially accessing the mainpage and trying to push/execute that funciton, I get the error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getModel' of undefined".

But when the Dialog has already been opened previously, then closed again and then the button on the mainpage gets pushed, the function call works fine without any errors.

Do I have to instantiate the controller somehow or how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try putting the getModel() method after you open the dialog. The first time, the dialog wasn't opened. So this.getView() returns undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying the different suggestions of @Blangero I eventually came up with a solution that worked.
(the ".bind(this)" way unfortunately doesn't work. That would've been the sleekest solution)

So here is what I did:

I defined the **manualDialogView** outside of any function my controller:

```
  sap.ui.define([
    'workspace/controller/ManualUpload.controller', 
  ],
  function(ManualUpload) {
     var oManualUploadController = new ManualUpload();
     var manualDialogView = sap.ui.view({ 
        viewName: "workspace.view.ManualDialog",
        controller: oManualUploadController,
        type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML 
     });    
     return BaseController.extend('workspace.controller.MainHeader', {
       ... 
        // rest of controller
        ...
 }
```

Then I instantiated my Main view in *onInit()* and added the **manualDialogView** as a dependant:

```
    onInit : function() {
        var view = this.getView();
        view.addDependent(manualDialogView);
   },
```

Finally, opening my **manualDialogView** is in a separate function and the function call I'd like to get from the other controller is working fine in another function:

```
onOpenManualDialog: function(oEvent) {
    var dialog = manualDialogView.byId("manualUploadDialog");           
    manualDialogView.callbackAPI = this.callbackAPI;
    dialog.open();
},

onExportBackendTable: function() {

    var backendData = oManualUploadController.onGenerateBackendData();
    ... not relevant code
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you own MainController and ManualUploadController, I'd suggest to put the function in MainController if you want to call it in both controller.

If you're using libraries, try to instantiate first.

But your problem is a bit complex.

If you want to get model, you can try to get it via Component instead.

If you want to solve the issue of failed to get view, you can try

```
var backendData = oManualUploadController.onGenerateBackendData().bind(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have code that you want to use in multiple controllers I would suggest putting that logic in a new file/class. Pass the app component to the constructor, because it has access to all models defined in the `manifest.json` and the `Component.js`.

**webapp/util/UploadHelper.js:**

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/base/Object"
], function (BaseObject) {
    "use strict";

    return BaseObject.extend("workspace.util.UploadHelper", {

        /**
         * @param {sap.ui.core.UIComponent} oComponent reference to the app's component
         */
        constructor: function (oComponent) {
            this._oComponent = oComponent;
            this._oResourceBundle = oComponent.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle();

            this._oModel = oComponent.getModel("odataDetails");
        },

        generateBackendData: function () {
            // you can access this._oModel here and do stuff
            return stuff;
        }
    });
});
```

Then in your controller you can do

**webapp/controller/MainHeader.controller.js**

```
sap.ui.define([
    "workspace/controller/BaseController",
    "workspace/util/UploadHelper" 
],
function(BaseController, UploadHelper) {
    "use strict";

    return BaseController.extend('workspace.controller.MainHeader', {

        onInit: function() {
            // pass your component.js to the constructor
            var oComponent = this.getOwnerComponent();
            this._oUploadHelper = new UploadHelper(oComponent);
            ...
        },

        onExportBackendTable: function() {
            var oBackendData = this._oUploadHelper.generateBackendData();
            ...
        }
    });
});
```